# FadeIn certain text in a paragraph and than other text Jquery

Tags: jquery, fadein

I have a paragraph

```
<p>This is stack over flow. This is a programming website</p>
```

Now I want only the text 'stack over flow' fadeIn on page load with some css style and than fadeIn the rest text.

So how to do this. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<p><span class="2nd">This is </span><span class="1st">stack over flow</span><span class="2nd">. This is a programming website</span></p>
```

And use this jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("span").fadeOut(1);

        $(".2nd").fadeIn(3000);

        $(".1st").fadeIn(1000);

    });
</script>
```

I hope this was helpful, is yes pls mark otherwise pls let me know.

Comment: I have only the given paragraph at first time. How can I split that according to your answer.

Comment: u can place the above span in a <p> tag

Answer (score 0):

You have to separate your string with classes and use the fadein() callback.
Something like this should work :

HTML :

```
<span class="andThen">This is </span><span class="firstAppears">stack over flow.</span> <span id="andThen">This is a programming website</span>
```

JS:

```
$(".firstAppears").fadeIn('slow', function() {
     // first animation complete
     $(".andThen").fadeIn('slow');
});
```

Comment: But how to seprate the paragraph text in three different spans.

Comment: If you can't edit the <p> content to add span tags, you'll probably have to parse it with some substrings and rebuild the paragraph by setting its content with jquery html() function